# Wrong user-agent header when using IE selenium webdriver

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, user-agent

I have strange problem.
Normally, website I'm testing is made for IE8 and up. It checks user-agent header.
It works perfect when I'm doing it manually, but when I'm trying to connect using webdriver (IEDriverServer) it doesn't work.

When I look (using fiddler) at user agent header when manually connecting to my site, it is correct:

`User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; GTB7.4; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; MAAU; .NET4.0C; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0E)`

But when using webdriver it looks like IE5.5 is used:

`User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT 5.0; Trident/4.0; GTB7.4; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; SLCC2; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; MAAU; .NET4.0C; Tablet PC 2.0; .NET4.0E)`

I'm using :

- selenium-java-2.28.0 (used 2.20, 2.29 before, and it also not worked)
- Win7 Home premium sp1
- IE8.0
- `client: java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.28.0.jar -role webdriver -hub http:// localhost:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=iexplore,platform=WINDOWS, version="8.0"`
- hub: java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.29.0.jar -role hub
- Eclipse, Java.

Google says that I can't switch user-agent for IE. It is possible only for FF and Chrome. Unfortunately I'm forced to use IE.

Any hints? Suggestions? Is it a bug or I missed something?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What version of the IEDriverServer.exe are you using? In particular, are you using the 32-bit or 64-bit version of the executable? And which version of the browser are you using when you test manually, including 32- or 64-bit?

Comment: Both Driver and browser 64bit

Comment: Two follow up questions: First, what happens when you capture the traffic manually using 64-bit IE? Second, what happens when you use the 32-bit IEDriverServer.exe?

Comment: "Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
2.29.0.0
Listening on port 45149
3058 [Forwarding newSession on session null to remote] INFO org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient - I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
3058 [Forwarding newSession on session null to remote] INFO org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient - Retrying request"

Comment: I was totally wrong, I've mistaken IE versions. Sorry for that. Here is correction:
1) 32Bit browser - All ok - user-agent like in first example, site works perfect. 2) 32Bit IEdriverServer - user-agent like in first example, but something is wrong with sessions. (trace in previous comment because this one is too long). 3) 64Bit IEDriverserver with spoofed user-agent header in fiddler - site works perfect. 4) 64Bit IE - has probably a problem, it behaves like I described (wrong user agent)

Comment: So manually, 64-bit IE shows the wrong user agent? If that's true, then I would expect to see the "incorrect" user agent when using 64-bit IE via WebDriver. As for "something [being] wrong with sessions", you should read [this blog post](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2012/12/seeing-info-messages-in-log-does-not.html).

Comment: I installed IE9 and the same situation, strange. I found on google, registry file which helped me with that. Although still have problem with that newSession issue, but it is working now. So thank you for your hints, that allowed me to solve my problem.